# Como recorrer un arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Como recorrer un arraylist mientras no encuentre el elemento y si al final no esta ese elemento añadirlo a la lsita

Comment: Bienvenida Elena para poder entender mejor tu pregunta debemos de ver [mcve], edita la pregunta y muestra el codigo que tienes ya

Answer (score 2):

Poder hacerlo así, no hace falta recorrerlo, podes usar la funcion `contains`:

```
if (!myArray.contains(elemento)) { //si tu arraylist no contiene el elemento
   myArray.add(elemento);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay un método llamado `contains`  para poder comparar:

```
Arrays.asList(array).contains(elemento)
```

el ejemplo deberia quedar asi:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int [] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int comparador = 7;
        if (!Arrays.asList(arr).contains(comparador)){ //validamos si el elemento esta en la lista
            arr[arr.length - 1] = comparador; // Agregamos el elemento
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```